# Using the xml-maven-plugin offline

Tags: xml, maven-2, maven, xslt

I have configured the `xml-maven-plugin` to run with a locally defined XSLT schema, in order to validate all XSLT files defined in a project:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>validate-xsl</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>validate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <validationSets>
            <validationSet>
                 <dir>${project.build.resources[0].directory}</dir>
                 <systemId>${project.build.testResources[0].directory}/schema-for-xslt20.xsd</systemId>
                 <includes>
                     <include>**/*.xsl</include>
                 </includes>
             </validationSet>
         </validationSets>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

However, once I yank out the network cable it does not run succesfully:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:validate (default-cli) on project projectdotnet: Failed to load schema with public ID null, system ID /home/robert/..../src/test/resources/schema-for-xslt20.xsd: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xs:schema' to a(n) 'element declaration' component. -> [Help 1]
```

I've read that this could be solved by [using an XML catalog](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/validate-mojo.html#catalogs), but I did not find any complete reference for this to work with the plugin.

How can I make this validation work offline?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify catalog in validate goal properties as described here:
http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/validation.html

XML Catalogs is standard thing, have you tried it and it and it doesn't work? Essentially you would need to map your schema (or DTD) namespace URLinto location in your local file system.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example of how such a catalog should like for the XSLT schema?

Comment: I don't have it handy but I recall it was working of past project. This looks pretty close to what I've been using: http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/spec-2001-08-06.html#ex.docbook.cat

Comment: Also, have you tried to run maven in 'offline' mode? Just a wild guess :)